# Which MySQL connector do I use: mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar or mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar What is the difference?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I am preparing to use jdbc for the first time and am in the process of installing the jdbc driver for MySQL.

However, it is unclear to me which of these files to move to the WEB_INF/lib folder in Eclipse.  They both seem to contain the same content and are included together in the downloaded zip file for the MySQL connector.

I have searched everywhere but have been unable to find any documentation to explain which of these files to use.

Comment: I can assure you one thing: your computer is not going to melt when you just try it. This seems a simple packaging mistake, either file should work.

Comment: @Gimby It is not a packaging mistake, it is an intentional change, see my answer.

Comment: @Gimby Of course, I would have just dropped the `-bin` from the name. But I assume Oracle wants to preserve that for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel friend, you already have my upvote with a blessing :) Any reservations I have about this decision are undone by the fact that it is quite openly and clearly explained in the release notes.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I thought you were joking, but I just downloaded the zip from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ and, indeed, it contains both.

The `mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar` and `mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar` are binary identical, except for the `META-INF/INDEX.LIST` (which contains the actual jar filename). I have unzipped both and compared them using kdiff3.

In short: you can use either: whatever you prefer.

This change is mentioned in `CHANGES` as:

> - Fix for Bug#27231383, PROVIDE MAVEN-FRIENDLY COMMERCIAL PACKAGES WITHOUT "-BIN".

Interestingly, there is no bug 27231383 in the MySQL bug tracker (the number is too high for the 'normal' bugs listed), so maybe it is from another system within Oracle.

In addition, the [online Connector/J 5.1.46 release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/5.1/en/news-5-1-46.html) mentions:

> The bundle for Connector/J 5.1 delivered by Oracle now contains an
>   additional jar package with the name `mysql-connector-java-5.1.ver.jar`
>   (`mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.ver.jar` for commercial
>   bundles). It is identical with the other jar package with the original
>   package named `mysql-connector-java-5.1.ver-bin.jar`
>   (`mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.ver-bin.jar` for commercial
>   bundles), except for its more Maven-friendly file name. (Bug #27231383)

Presumably, given the closer match to Maven naming conventions, this makes it easier to install the library in local/company Maven repositories (eg if you don't want, or legally can't, use Maven Central).

But to repeat: they are the same, and you can use either one.

Comment: I am impressed by how much you were able to investigate into this issue.  Thank you for your answer.  This was very helpful.